# Regular expression for Credit Card Expiry date validation in Javascript/angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a textfield, and when I enter credit card expiry date (mm/yy) in that textfield, I validate the date with Javascript. I have tried the following regular expressions:

```
var s = "11/12";                                                        
/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{2}$/.test(s);
```

In the above expression, month validation works but it takes 00,12,17 for year. How do I validate year as well?

Comment: are you trying to validate to check future date , because year 2000 can be 00, 2017 can be 17 ?

Comment: Using regex in general doesn't seem like a very good solution - you need to know the current date if you don't want to keep modifying it every month/year, and regex is typically hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for correctness, you could do a much more correct date validation if you used JavaScript's Date API. For instance:

```js
function validateExpiry (input) {
  // ensure basic format is correct
  if (input.match(/^((0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{2})$/)) {
    const {0: month, 1: year} = input.split("/");

    // get midnight of first day of the next month
    const expiry = new Date("20" + year, month);
    const current = new Date();
    
    return expiry.getTime() > current.getTime();
    
  } else return false;
}

console.log("01/32", validateExpiry("01/32"));
console.log("01/19", validateExpiry("04/18"));
console.log("05/18", validateExpiry("05/18"));
console.log("05.18", validateExpiry("05.18"));
console.log("00/23", validateExpiry("00/23"));
console.log("invalid", validateExpiry("invalid"));
```

Comment: You regex will validate 00 with \d. Change it to ^((0[1-9]|1[1-2])\/\d{2})$